# Why I don't see record in database from my test project?

Tags: android, robotium, android-testing

Hї!

I have wrote test for my application. I need add item to database throught UI interface (using robotium) and then I want to check if item exists in database using SQLiteDatabase.

Item is added succesfully (I see new record in database after test finished), but isExistsInDb in my test class returns false. I do not understand why. Could you please help me.
Thanks!

Activity class:

```
public abstract class EditActivity {


   // Some code .....

    @Override
    public void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        initButtonCancelOk();
    }

    protected void validateAndSave() {
        try {
            formValidator.validateAll();
            if (formValidator.isFormValid()) {
                DatabaseOpenHelper doh = new DatabaseOpenHelper(this);
                Dao d = new Dao(doh);
                d.add(fetchObjectFromUi());
                finish(); // destroy this activity
            } else {
                ToastImage.makeImageText(context,
                        R.drawable.warning,
                        formValidator.getMessages(),
                        Toast.LENGTH_SHORT
                    ).show();
            }
        } catch (Exception e) {
            Toast.makeText(context, " Error during validate form ", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }

    private void initButtonCancelOk() {
        btnOk = (Button) findViewById(R.id.btn_ok);
        btnOk.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {

            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                validateAndSave();
            }
        });
    }    
}
```

Test class:

```
public class AddItemSmokeTest extends extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<EditActivity> {

    protected Activity activity;
    protected Solo solo;

    public AddItemSmokeTest() {
        super("com.myapp", EditActivity.class);
        Intent i = createIntent(2);
        setActivityIntent(i);
        activity = getActivity();
        solo = new Solo(getInstrumentation(), activity);
        solo.sleep(1000); // interval between tests
    }

    protected Intent createIntent(long transType) {
        Intent i = new Intent();
        i.putExtra(INTENT_VALUE_MODE_NAME, MODE_INSERT_TRANSACTION);
        i.putExtra(INTENT_VALUE_TYPE_ID_NAME, transType);
        return i;
    }

    @Override
    protected void tearDown() throws Exception {

    }

    protected void setIncomExpenseData(AbsTransIncomeExpenseTestData testData) {
        solo.pressSpinnerItem(CATEGORY_SPN_INDEX, testData.getCategorySpinnerPos());
        solo.pressSpinnerItem(ACCOUNT_SPN_INDEX, testData.getAccountSpinnerPos());
        solo.typeText((EditText) activity.findViewById(com.rirdev.moneycounter.R.id.et_sum), testData.getSum());
        solo.typeText((EditText) activity.findViewById(com.rirdev.moneycounter.R.id.et_comment), testData.getComment());
    }

    @Smoke
    public void testAddIncomeTransaction() throws Exception {
        initForType(TransactionType.INCOME);
        AbsTransIncomeExpenseTestData testData = new IncomeTestData();
        setIncomExpenseData(testData);
        solo.clickOnButton(OK);
        //solo.getActivityMonitor();
        assertTrue( 
                    "Item" + testData.getComment() + " was not added ",
                    isExistsInDb(activity, Transactions.TABLE_NAME, Transactions.DESCRIPTION, testData.getComment())
                  );
    }

    protected static boolean isExistsInDb(Context context, String tableName, String commentFieldName, String comment) {

        DatabaseOpenHelper doh = new DatabaseOpenHelper(context);
        SQLiteDatabase db = doh.getDatabaseReadable();
        Cursor cursor = null;
        try {
            String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + commentFieldName + " = \"" + comment + "\"";
            cursor = db.rawQuery(query, null);
            cursor.moveToFirst();
            if (cursor.getInt(0) > 1) {
                return true;
            }
            return false;
        } finally {
            if (cursor != null) {
                cursor.close();
            }
            db.close();
            doh.close();
        }

    }

}
```

**Update:**

If I run test the second time it is passed because in database exists item added by previous test.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I recommend to use use `parametrized statement`, your approach is danger and not much clear.
Also much better is use `getCount()` method.

```
String query = "SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName + " WHERE columnName = ?";
cursor = db.rawQuery(query, new Sring[] {comment});
int count = 0;
if (cursor.getCount() > 0) {
   cursor.moveToFirst();
   count = cursor.getInt(0);
}
if (count > 0) {
   return true;
}
else {
   return false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

in where clasue use 'string' instead of "string".....

```
"SELECT COUNT(*) FROM " + tableName + " WHERE " + commentFieldName + " = '" + comment + "'";
```

Comment: even better, use bind variables

Comment: @Dheeresh Singh I changed quotes. The result is the same.